# FTL by exploiting the frame rate of reality

Tags: science-based, space, computers, faster-than-light

I'm considering a possible method of FTL travel for my science fiction universe. I stumbled upon [this Quora post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-FPS-of-real-life) which supported a concept that I had.

Does it make sense to liken the inverse of Planck time (the time it takes light [or any massless particle, I suppose] to travel one Planck length in a vacuum) to the frame rate of reality?

If so, by increasing the frame rate within the native reference frame (using a method analogous to how one might increase the frame rate of their gaming computer [e.g.: reducing the resolution of the universe, overclocking the universe's CPU]), could you allow yourself to accelerate beyond the speed of light without creating any time-breaking paradoxes? Any ideas for how this might work?

Comment: Do you assume we live in simulation?

Comment: As far as we know time and space are *not* quantised. [Planck time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_time) is simply the smallest time interval of which it makes sense to speak of at the current level of understanding of physics; but time is not made up of an integer number of Plank intervals, unlike, for example, electrical charge which always consists of an integer number of elementary charges. Not to mention that there is no such thing as universal time, and not even an universal timeline.

Comment: In a really weird way, this is sorta what relativity already does.  As you approach the speed of light, the universe around you appears to contract as your timestream slows.  As a result, from your perspective it would seem like you crossed many lightyears in a matter of moments because from your perspective the universe is much smaller than it was when you were at rest.  Time dilation does very strange things.

Comment: I think that you have too many questions here.  I will not vote to close but I hope that you can edit this to be a bit more streamlined.  This is an interesting idea.

Comment: As a computer scientist approaching it from that direction, this doesn't seem to hold water. Increasing the frame rate (simulation speed) of the universe means everything happens faster from an outside perspective, but within the simulation, you'd still think you took the full time to travel. That's why all ftl discussions focus on reference frames. If you adjust the entire universe, without removing yourself from it, you subject yourself to the same effects and won't notice a difference.

Comment: @ShadoCat If you think there are too many questions here, you should vote to close so that the question is put on hold before people come and make answers - the whole point of the system is to put questions that need editing on hold so that the edits don't invalidate answers!

Comment: Sadly we do not understand processes in those time intervals very well at all. Currently it is impossible to answer such questions

Comment: @AlexP That's the trouble with science. Things get rethought. Let me introduce to Lee Smolin's  *Time Reborn: From the Crisis in Physics to the Future of the Universe* (2013) which makes an interesting case for the possibility of universal time. That doesn't make right, but it does undermine confidence in assertions that there is no such thing as universal time.

Comment: @Stephan So let's say that you increase the frame rate within your native reference frame only. Do you think that the contents of the reference frame would appear to be (and effectively be) moving faster than light outside from outside, but appear to be accelerating normally from within?

Comment: Increasing your own frame rate will make everything else appear slower. That's what MozerSchmozer was getting at with the speed of light. The universe already appears to tie framerate with velocity.

Comment: Hi Christopher. It looks like you might have created more than one account on the site. See [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) in the [help] for information on how to get them merged.

Comment: @ChristopherCostello you might want to look at white holes or inflatons. Although, to the best of our knowledge at the moment, space and time are continuous (not having frames), you can achieve "sped up" effects with either of these concepts.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks I requested a merge.

Comment: This concept would have made a fascinating story in the golden age of science fiction.  Basically, the Quora discussion and your question suggest that if we can change the way we experience time, we might have the ability to travel FTL.  That would be a godlike ability (obviously brought about by an enhancing machine) that has the feel of Anne McCaffrey's "[The Rowan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Rowan)" and its sequels.  I love the idea!  But, alas, it has no foundation in real physics... but that didn't stop Ms. McCaffrey... and it shouldn't stop you.